# Maven: specify the outputDirectory only for packaging a jar?

Tags: maven-2, maven

How can I specify the outputDirectory only for packaging a jar?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html this shows all parameters, but how can I set them in the commandline or pom.xml?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

on command line

```
-DoutputDirectory=<path>
```

and in pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>/my/path</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried that already: mvn -DoutputDirectory=/tmp package without success. how can I tell mvn that this option should be used by the jar:jar goal ?

Comment: on command line I think you can't specify it for a signel plugin

Comment: thanks. this was my first question on stackoverflow. Im impressed about the response time :-)

Comment: you can specify some parameters on the command line using system properties, for others you have to use tricks (see my answer)

Comment: To build into project top level directory, use:      <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}</outputDirectory>

Comment: did not work ..

Answer (score 50):

### Parameter Expressions

About command line usage:

[The parameter documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#outputDirectory) specifies that the parameter is initialized to the value of the property `${project.build.directory}` (which is the property referring to the target folder)

Here's what this means:

> For mojos that are intended to be
>   executed directly from the CLI, their
>   parameters usually provide a means to
>   be configured via system properties
>   instead of a `<configuration/>` section
>   in the POM. The plugin documentation
>   for those parameters will list an
>   expression that denotes the system
>   properties for the configuration. In
>   the mojo above, the parameter url is
>   associated with the expression
>   `${query.url}`, meaning its value can be
>   specified by the system property
>   `query.url` as shown below:

```
mvn myquery:query -Dquery.url=http://maven.apache.org
```

**Reference:**

- [Guide to Configuring Plug-ins > Generic Configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Generic_Configuration)

### Configuring ${project.build.directory}

However, `${project.build.directory}` is not a system property, [it's a property](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/BuildBase.html#getDirectory%28%29) of the [Project](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-project/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html)'s [`Build`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/2.2.1/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Build.html) object.

You can't set maven's internal properties directly on the command line, but you can get there with a little trick by adding placeholders in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <directory>${dir}</directory>
</build>
```

Now, the output directory is set via the property from the command line (using `-Ddir=somedirectory`). Downside: now you always have to use the `-Ddir` parameter on the command line.

### Using Profiles

But there's help here, too. Just use a profile when you want to configure the directory:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>conf</id>
        <build>
            <directory>${dir}</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you can either do

```
# everything goes in someOtherDir instead of target
mvn clean install -Pconf -Ddir=someOtherDir
```

or plain old

```
# everything goes in target
mvn clean install
```

### Configuring the Jar Plugin

Now if you just want to change the jar outputDirectory from the command line without redirecting everything from target, we'll modify the profile to configure the plugin from a command line property:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>conf</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The usage is identical to above:

```
# everything goes in someOtherDir instead of target
mvn clean install -Pconf -Ddir=someOtherDir
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @Sean Patrick Floyd for the excellent explanation.

Instead of creating a profile and using `mvn` always by `-P` switch, I'd like to use another way that making a default value of property ${dir}.

Just define `${dir}`'s default value as `${project.build.directory}`

```
<properties>
    <dir>${project.build.directory}</dir>
</properties>
```

and same as @Sean Patrick Floyd, set outputDirectory.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${dir}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now you can either do

```
# everything goes in someOtherDir instead of target
mvn clean install -Ddir=someOtherDir
```

or plain old

```
# everything goes in target
mvn clean install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish copy dependency jars as well to a target folder, use maven-dependency-plugin.

```
<project>
  ...
  ...

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>

</project>
```