# Migrating Ant targets to Maven goals

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I am migrating existing Ant project to Maven. But I am facing a problem while building the project in Maven as I have to achieve the existing targets.

I want to copy the files based on ENV I passed.
In Ant I am using like below:

```
<fileset dir="${scripts.dir}" />
            <filtermapper>
                <replacestring from=".${param.environment}" to="" />
            </filtermapper>
```

**EDIT** I have achived this:

[image]

**Edit**

Now I want to keep my files as below:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what it is you want to do exactly? It's really unclear from your question.

Comment: Why have the 2 targets have to run one after another ? What is the expected output format ?

Comment: @jah, I missed 1 point to add, I have to run 1 *-build.xml for one region (It takes 1 set of properties like DB credentials, web services details and etc) and After I deploy that I may run for another region with second *-build.xml.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom build output structure, then you should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar).

You might want to familiarize yourself with the concept of [Maven build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), that should allow you to have different build configurations based on an external setting.

If you want to copy files as a part of Maven built, then you should take a look at the [Maven Copy Resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html)