# How to create war in specific location using maven tomcat plugin

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin, maven-tomcat-plugin

I was using maven's tomcat plugin for deploying my web application to tomcat server. now i need the same war file in a different location(not directly deploy to tomcat server.). So that i can manually copy my war file to another machine's and deploy it.

My current pom.xml configuration is

```
      <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>staging</id>
        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                             <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                            <server>mytomcat</server>
                            <path>/project1</path>
                                <username>xxxxxxx</username>
                            <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Were you able to implement this or do you need any more help?

Comment: Also please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use profiles.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>otherOutputDir</id>
        <build>
            <directory>yourDirectory</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Refer

[Maven: How to change path to target directory from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908013/maven-how-to-change-path-to-target-directory-from-command-line) 
and

[Maven: specify the outputDirectory only for packaging a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add the `Spring Boot Maven Plugin` to your project's pom.xml (with Maven 3.2 or later) as shown below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

along with the type of artifact that you need, ie `jar` or `war` within the `project` tag of your pom as shown below:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Next whenever you run the `package` phase of maven (with `mvn package` command for eg), the artifact would be generated within the `target` folder. More info on the same is provided in the Spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html).

For other ways of generating the war/jar artifact, please refer to this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven).