# Bash script to get the outputDirectory tag value of a fileset from Maven assembly.xml

Tags: bash, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I need a Bash script to get the value of outputDirectory tag under fileset from Maven assembly.xml, so I could handle created files.

I don't mean the actual character set between the opening and closing tags, but the default value if the tag is empty or the value of the variable if there is one in that tag.

I created a an assembly xml with different fileSet tags, just to display various cases I need to handle. I want a script which will give me the paths of the output directory as Maven sees them

```
<assembly>
    <id>${deploy.name}</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>    
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/examples</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>${Common.shared.location}</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Update:
Maven saves the created file in the output directory.
The base directory of of **outputDirectory** is by default the value of **${project.build.directory}** and there is nice explanation about it here [Maven: specify the outputDirectory only for packaging a jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757426/maven-specify-the-outputdirectory-only-for-packaging-a-jar?rq=1)

I have a variable in a script, which I want to have the path of the folder where Maven would save the output file. After each of the example outputDirectory tags below, there is a line which I believe should be the value of the variable I want.

value of ${project.build.directory}

/
I'm not sure

/examples
value of ${project.build.directory}/examples

${Common.shared.location}
depends on the value of the ${Common.shared.location} variable

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output? Can you add an example assembly.xml file (anonymized if it contains private info)? Can you show what you have tried to do so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` with regex:

```sh
for match in $(sed -n 's|<outputDirectory>\(.*\)</outputDirectory>|\1|p' assembly.xml) ; do
  echo "$match"
done
```

**Explanation:**

The `sed 's|...|...|p'` prints matches for the regex `<outputDirectory>\(.*\)</outputDirectory>`, which matches any text between two `<outputDirectory>` tags. The `for match in ...` iterates over the matches and prints them to stdout.

Comment: Thanks. 
But I hope there is a general solution that would give me the value of the outputDirectory tag whether it is a plain value of a variable (in which case I want the *value* of the parameter.

For finding tag value string I use the following:
    TAG_VALUE=`echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:properties/x:neededTag/text()' | xmllint --shell ../folder/pom.xml | grep -v /`

Comment: @Avi Can you add an example of your expected output to your question? I'm not sure if I understand